# How do I extract from db the categories and subcatories of a product?

Tags: category, query

This is my try:

```
 SELECT fs.entity_id, fs.path, fs.name,c.level 
     FROM catalog_category_product_index AS PI
      INNER JOIN catalog_category_flat_store_1 AS fs 
      ON pi.category_id = fs.entity_id
      INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity c 
      ON c.entity_id = pi.category_id
     WHERE pi.product_id = 1
```

I know about the path. but i want to extract the data in other format:

category1/subcategory1.1/subcategory1.1.1 , category1/subcategory 1.2/ subcategory 1.2.1

Is there a way to extract the data like that ?

Comment: Do you have a good justification to use SQL and not models?

Comment: is this relevant ? i want to use sql

Comment: You should get the categories ids in the `path` column after running your query. You should get something like this: `1/3/15/24`.  `1` is the root of all roots. `3` is the `root category` and `15` and `24` are the category ids. `15` is parent for `24`, but I think you better join directly with `catalog_category_entity`.

Comment: It is relevant if you don't know how or why use a model instead of a SQL query.

Comment: I just want simply use sql queries

Comment: @Marius i know, but i want to get all of the data with the described format. Is there a way to get like that ? categoryName/subcategoryName/ ......

Comment: @Chester. I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select cc.* from catalog_category_entity cc
   join catalog_category_product cp on cc.entity_id = cp.category_id
   where cp.product_id = {{your product id}};
```